# Java Swing: How to build Connect 4 GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

So I'm trying to create a Connect 4 GUI program in Java using the MVC pattern, where this class is the Model:

```
public class ConnectFourGame {

    private Board board;
    private Player playerX;
    private Player playerO;
    private int turnCount;
    private CheckWinnerAlgorithm checkWinner;

    /**
     * Constructs a new ConnectFourGame instance.
     */
    public ConnectFourGame() {
        this.board = new Board();
        this.playerX = new Player('X');
        this.playerO = new Player('O');
        this.turnCount = 1;
        this.checkWinner = new CheckWinnerAlgorithm();
    }

    /**
     * Accesses the current game board.
     * @return a Board object representing the current game board
     */
    public Board getBoard() {
        return this.board;
    }

    /**
     * Accesses player X and their attributes. 
     * @return a PlayerX object
     */
    public Player getPlayerX() {
        return this.playerX;
    }

    /**
     * Accesses player O and their attributes.
     * @return a PlayerO object
     */
    public Player getPlayerO() {
        return this.playerO;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the winner of the game.
     * @return a CheckWinnerAlgorithm object containing the winner token
     */
    public CheckWinnerAlgorithm getWinner() {
        return this.checkWinner;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whose turn it is based on the game's turn counter.
     * @return the Player whose turn it currently is
     */
    public Player determineTurn() {
        if (this.turnCount % 2 == 0) {
            return this.playerO;
        } 
        else {
            return this.playerX;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assesses whether a player move can be made, placing a token if valid.
     * @param colNum An int specifying the column chosen by the player
     * @param playerToken A char representing the player's token
     * @return a boolean, true if a valid move has been made and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean moveIsMade(int colNum, char playerToken) {
        // move cannot be made if selected column is full
        if (board.getBoard()[0][colNum-1] != ' ') {
            System.out.println("The selected column is full.");
            return false;
        }
        // if column is not full, place token at bottom-most available spot
        for (int row=0; row<6; row++) {
            if (board.getBoard()[row][colNum-1] != ' ') {
                board.getBoard()[row-1][colNum-1] = playerToken;
                this.turnCount++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        // place token at bottom of empty column
        board.getBoard()[5][colNum-1] = playerToken;
        this.turnCount++;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Specifies whether the game is over.
     * @return a boolean, true if the game is over and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isOver() {
        if (this.checkWinner.findWinner(this.board)!=' ') {
            this.resetGame();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the game to a beginning state.
     */
    public void resetGame() {
        this.board.clearBoard();
        this.checkWinner.resetWinnerToken();
        this.turnCount = 1;
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to start building the View class with Swing GUI elements. Below is a rough mockup of the GUI I have in mind:

[image: Connect 4 GUI mockup]

The top row are JButtons which will drop a token into the corresponding column of the board when clicked. I'm thinking of using a **2D 6*7 array of JLabels** to represent the board. **How can I display this in the above manner**?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"...so if anyone could provide an outline of the methods required in each class that would be a fantastic help!"` -- is overly broad and likely outside of the purview of this site, same for multi-part questions. This is a question/answer site, so please one specific question per post.

Comment: You should already have a simple view - The JFrame + some buttons/labels, etc. Attach some action listeners into some places to your view, then update your model accordingly. That's the controllers

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, I've updated the post to ask a single specific question.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your help. I've now revised the question to be specifically about how to implement the GUI elements - any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I display JLabels in the above manner (like a grid)?

You would use the [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Your other alternative is to use a JPanel as a drawing panel, and draw the game board.  By drawing the game board, you can make the pieces circles instead of squares.

> How do I set up handling for all this in the Controller class?

You will have more than one controller class.  In Java Swing, action listeners are the controllers in your model / view / controller pattern.

The JButtons to drop pieces will each have a separate action listener.